Why is the mirror in sculpt mode dislocated?

I already mirrored it in x axis but why isn't it anchored to the middle? This is in sculpt mode and I haven't remeshed it. The x and y axis is also dislocated. What should I do?

hello what do you mean by anchored? Could you please highlitght the problem? Don't forget to apply the scale, the brush may be distorted because you have an uneven scale

Maybe add a few more screenshots, specifically one in object mode with the object selected and the object's coordinates visible (the location, rotation and scale tab open and visible). Also one with the modifiers panel if there are any modifiers on the object.
Avoid cropping the screenshots to a small area, try to keep the whole window in the screenshot because it may include information relevant to the question (even if sometimes the person asking doesn't know that the information is relevant).

It seems like 2 things happened here :

The model is rotated
Model's origin is not in the model's center.

__
To fix this go into Object mode and then (with only this model selected) :

Ctrl+A > Rotation - to apply rotation
Right Mouse Click > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry - to place Origin to the model's center

